# How to add a second MySQL increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table:

```
TABLE
--------------------------------------
Unique ID | Increment ID | value | 
--------------------------------------
```

How would you make sure that the 'Increment ID' value auto increments if it sees that the Unique ID already has a value. For example

```
Table
--------------------------------------
Unique_ID | Increment_ID | value | 
=====================================
random1   | 1            | value1
random1   | 2            | value2
random2   | 1            | value3
random2   | 3            | value5
--------------------------------------
```

And if I send it a row of:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (Unique_ID,value) VALUES (random2,value6);
```

And what I would like to get is:

```
--------------------------------------
Unique_ID | Increment_ID | value  | 
=====================================
random1   | 1            | value1
random1   | 2            | value2 
random2   | 1            | value3 
random2   | 3            | value5 
random2   | 2            | value6 
--------------------------------------
```

Can MySQL even do this? Or should this be done in PHP?

Comment: Unless something has changed in recent versions, this _can_ be done using a primary key of (Unique_ID, Increment_ID) _if_ the MyISAM storage engine is used; but then you lose basic features like foreign keys (and triggers I think).

Comment: You could do this using ON BEFORE INSERT and ON BEFORE UPDATE Triggers. But string keys aren't the best choice.

Comment: @Uueerdo, you can use triggers with MyISAM, but using MyISAM means you lose transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys, and all four ACID capabilities.

Comment: @BillKarwin ah, yeah, I remembered there was stuff besides foreign keys, just couldn't remember the specifics.

Comment: I really wouldn't bother trying to do this. Just store an AI - you can always calculate this kind of sequence on the fly, but it's not worth it to. give up innodb for myisam

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports an auto-increment-per-group feature only for MyISAM tables.

But this is not a good enough reason to use MyISAM tables.

To implement auto-increment-per-group, an INSERT needs exclusive access to the set of rows in the group, to make sure it can calculate the next increment ID for that group without creating a race condition with other concurrent sessions doing inserts to the same group.

This means your transaction needs to lock the table against concurrent inserts.

MyISAM uses table-locking during writes anyway, so it can support this special kind of auto-increment behavior.

But a row-level locking storage engine like InnoDB doesn't support it. It would hinder concurrent inserts, and many features of MySQL are designed to help concurrent work.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a way to do it:

The MYSQL table *has* to be in MyISAM format. To do this (in phpmyadmin), go to the table, then go to the 'Operations' tab. In 'Operations' change the storage 'Storage Engine' to MyISAM. More info on: http://richardcummings.info/convert-myisam-to-innodb-using-phpmyadmin/

Now to make it increment:

Go to the table 'column' page, and make BOTH the 'Unique_ID' and 'Increment_ID' primary keys. Then set the 'Increment_ID' to 'auto_increment'. More info at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Not sure if this is the *BEST* way to do it, but it is certainly *A* way.